# Prove:$\left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right)^x\left[ x\ln \left( 1+\frac1x \right)+\frac1{1+x} \right]<\mathrm{e},\quad x\in (0,+\infty )$.

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function

> Prove inequality: ${{\left( 1+\dfrac{1}{x} \right)}^{x}}\left[ x\ln \left( 1+\dfrac{1}{x} \right)+\dfrac{1}{1+x} \right]<\operatorname{e},\quad x\in (0,+\infty )$.

Comment: Notice that the LHS is monotonically increasing and the limit as $x\to\infty$ is $e$. Hence, conclude.

Comment: Questions which merely state a problem are discouraged on this site. We look for more context: where did you encounter the problem? Why is it of interest? What methods have you tried? You can edit the question to add this information. Separately, questions which are posed as commands are sometimes viewed on this site as impolite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)={{\left( 1+\dfrac{1}{x} \right)}^{x}}\left( x\ln \left( 1+\dfrac{1}{x} \right)+\dfrac{1}{1+x} \right)$.

Hence, $$f'(x)=\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\left(x(x+1)^2\ln^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+2(x+1)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-x-3\right)}{(x+1)^2}.$$
We'll prove that 
$$x(x+1)^2\ln^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+2(x+1)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-x-3>0$$ or
$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)>\frac{-x-1+\sqrt{(x+1)^2+x(x+1)^2(x+3)}}{x(x+1)^2}$$ or
$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)>\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3x+1}-1}{x(x+1)}.$$ 
Now, let $$g(x)=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3x+1}-1}{x(x+1)}.$$
Thus,
$$g'(x)=\frac{2x^3+9x^2+7x-2-2\sqrt{(x^2+3x+1)^3}}{2x^2(x+1)^2\sqrt{x^2+3x+1}}<0$$
because for which we need to prove that
$$2\sqrt{(x^2+3x+1)^3}>2x^3+9x^2+7x-2,$$
which is obvious for $2x^3+9x^2+7x-2\leq0$, but for $2x^3+9x^2+7x-2>0$ it gives
$$4(x^2+3x+1)^3>(2x^3+9x^2+7x-2)^2$$ or
$$x(11x^3+62x^2+107x+64)>0.$$
Id est, $g$ decreases and since $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}g(x)=0$, we got that $f$ increases and since
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=e,$$ 
we are done!

Comment: Thank you, this question from the inequality $\frac{{{(n+2)}^{n+1}}}{{{(n+1)}^{n}}}-\frac{{{(n+1)}^{n}}}{{{n}^{n-1}}}<\operatorname{e},\quad n\in \mathbb{{N}^{*}}$.

Comment: @mathtex I think I saw your last inequality before.